# Как сделать релиз в GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Видел рекомендации сделать тег с приложенным файлом, но на него ограничение 10 мб, а мой билд занимает 300 мб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Залил в облако и оставил ссылку в теге.